# Where do I find Recent Apps?

Tags: recents-screen

I am trying to map my Recent Apps to a gesture, instead of home button long-press.  However, I can't seem to find the location of the Recent Apps function.  Before Lollipop I think I found in Activities > Settings; now I don't see it anywhere there.  Anyone know perchance where Recent Apps is located?

I'm using Android 5.0.1 on a Samsung Galaxy s4.

Comment: Which launcher are you using? I think this may be launcher dependent, but I can't be sure

Comment: Also, what's your device model and Android version? There's never such setting on vanilla Android (Nexus 4~5, KitKat~Marshmallow).

Comment: @1990clb The launcher is Lightning Launcher.  I used to use Nova for a while, I think both Nova and LL used to have Recent Apps in the same place, in the Activities > Settings section.

Comment: @AndrewT. It's a Samsung Galaxy s4.  The Android version is 5.0.1 (Lollipop).